# Get total stats of a work item field by each user

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

**End Goal** - Essentially what I'm trying to do through Azure DevOps is get the total completed story points (which is a field on all work items) by each developer on the team and then take that data and compare it to tracked time on each work item with toggl API.

**Problem** - I cannot seem to find anything that lets me do this through the Azure DevOps REST API. I actually cannot find anything that lets me get all of the work items based on criteria like by the person assigned, where I could then carry it the rest of the way. I would even take all of the work items where I would then have to do all of the filtering and grouping myself.

I'm attempting to do this with node via https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api but am happy to do it without a client library if needed.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried using the Azure DevOps REST API to get all of the work items but cannot see a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get work items from a query, the API is [Wiql - Query By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

For this you need the Query ID, so create a query that returns items with assigned to a user, save the query, and now you can see the id in the url:

[image]

When you have the query results you can iterate the work items and get the work items details (all the fields values) with [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Api:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

It's Rest API so you can do it in which languauge you want (Java, C#, Node.js, PowerShell, etc.).

Small example with PowerShell:

```
$user = ""
$token = "YOUR-PAT-HERE"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql/{queryId}?api-version=5.0"
$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$query.workItems.ForEach({

  $wiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$($_.id)?api-version=5.0"
  $workItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wiUrl -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

})
```